# How to improve visibility of failure cause in GitHub actions

Tags: github, github-actions

We are using Github actions to validate our code, build, and publish an artifact.  We have a number of checks which happen within the same Job:

- Run prettier
- Run typescript compiler to check types
- Run tests

When one fails right now, the UI looks like this in the PR:

[image: Github actions failure from PR view]

And this from the Job View:

[image: Github actions failure from job view]

Is it possible for us to provide more information about which step failed higher up so we don't have to dig into the raw output of the runner?

Ideally we could just see a red X next to the step name.

e.g.

❌ Prettier

I am open to other suggestions though, anyway to speed up figuring out which step caused the job to fail.